# Creating alias for .onion addresses

Tags: onion-services

I have a few .onion address and I want to make them operation system wide aliases so everytime I entered their alias, OS resolves them to their original .onion address and and then tor opens them.
I tried to accomplish this by adding them in hosts file (e.g /etc/hosts) but seems that tor does not care about hosts file.
example:

```
fvadgbdfgbdfg5vdg46dg6v4df6gv4dfgd6f4g8vdf4g864.onion   blah.fx
g546vgvhgewg34grthrth45hg5tgt5rgrsgdfsg45gyregd.onion   foo.fx
```

Where can I add these aliases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your closest option would be tor's [`MapAddress` option](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#MapAddress). You can use this to set up an alias for all connections made by the tor client.

For example:

```
MapAddress blah.fx fvadgbdfgbdfg5vdg46dg6v4df6gv4dfgd6f4g8vdf4g864.onion
MapAddress  foo.fx g546vgvhgewg34grthrth45hg5tgt5rgrsgdfsg45gyregd.onion
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked wherever I entered tor socks proxy address (9050), but there's still a problem. torsocks does not follow these Mapped Addresses. How to solve this one?

Comment: The application you're running under torsocks is probably making a DNS request for your address, and this might not get mapped. You should instead try mapping an IP address to your onion so that the application does not make a DNS request. For example `MapAddress 192.168.55.55 fvadgbdfgbdfg5vdg46dg6v4df6gv4dfgd6f4g8vdf4g864.onion`.